# Installing Torch has changed Jupyter Notebook configuration

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, torch

I was running Jupyter Notebook with Caffe. After installing Torch, Jupyter Notebook has stopped working. It is producing an error:

```
I couldn't find a kernel matching Python 2. Please select a kernel:
```

But the only option available is 'iTorch'. How can I reconfigure it please? Thanks.

---

Typing jupyter kernelspec list produces:

```
[ListKernelSpecs] WARNING | Native kernel (python2) is not available
[ListKernelSpecs] WARNING | Native kernel (python2) is not available
Available kernels:
  itorch    /home/user/.ipython/kernels/itorch
```

How can I reinstall the python2 kernel? ipython kernelspec install --user did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Torch adversely affected my ipython installation. After removing ipython and reinstalling, everything is working as expected. This is what I did:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove ipython
sudo pip uninstall ipython
git clone https://github.com/ipython/ipython.git
cd ipython
sudo pip install -e .
```

If anyone knows what Torch did, please post. Thanks.